Mongodb $bucket with $min
I am trying to get stats on how many docs were created per period
[
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$createdAt",
      boundaries: [
        ISODate("2024-06-01"),
        ISODate("2024-06-30"),
        ISODate("2024-07-01"),
        ISODate("2024-08-30")
      ],
      default: null,
      output: {
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        },
        arr: {
          $push: {
            createdAt: "$createdAt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $ne: null // exclude the default
      }
    }
  },
]

But I want to know in each period for example
ISODate("2024-06-01"),
ISODate("2024-06-30"),

between those dates (and for each period in boundaries) what are the minimum, maximum, and avg inserted docs per day...
any suggestion?

Can you provide sample json documents and expected output?
